# MySQL data range fetching start and finish dates from another table

Tags: mysql, date

I have two tables in my database:

**Dates**

```
id | startdate  | peakdate
1  | 2017-07-03 | 2017-05-29
```

**Macrocycle**

```
id |  date         | 
1  |  2017-07-03   | 
2  |  2017-07-10   | 
3  |  2017-07-17   |
```

I am using the following to generate rows for all dates in between the two dates:

```
select a.date 
from (
select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) Week as date
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.date between '2017-07-03' and '2018-01-24'
```

What can I do if I want the '2017-01-20' and '2018-01-24' to be replaced by the values read from startdate and peakdate in the Dates table. I further need to display the dates generated in the Macrocycle table with the id next to it, and not as a temporary table as it is doing. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

look at the following sql,maybe be helpful.

```
select a.date 
from (
select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) Week as date
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a,Dates b
where a.date between b.startdate  and b.peakdate
```

Comment: All I am getting is the first Monday's date after the current date

Comment: what do you want to say？What's the problem?

Comment: I would like it to fetch the startdate and peakdate values from the Dates table and then create a row with the Monday's date for each week in between the two dates. This column must be part of the Macrocycle table and must display the other fields too.